# Interviewing for my position

Tags: interviewing

I have recently accepted the new role in the same organization. I went through the ropes although I had already been notified about this new role and that I would be the best fit. The new role would have the same responsibilities but bigger scope and more leadership involvement.

We are then hiring someone to back-fill my current role. I would like to take part of the interviewing process. How would I ask my senior leaders my interest in sitting in on the interviews without sounding presumptuous?

Comment: Have you been trained in how to interview? or do you want to just observe?

Comment: What do you hope to gain from being part of the interview process?

Comment: @Neuromancer I haven't been trained to interview and it is also an opportunity to find out if the applicant can do the job. My leaders are both Medical Professionals, would be helpful to be present and gauge if the applicant really knows the technical part of the job.

Comment: @MaskedMan basically to see if the applicant fits the position. It's a mix of healthcare and information technology.

Comment: Who handled the technical questions when you interviewed for the previous position? Was it someone who held the position or was it someone with little to no experience?

Comment: @user3877489 and how do *you* gain from it?

Comment: @JeffO it was a newly created position when I applied, their data mining and reporting requirements prior to hiring me were outsourced from other departments within the organization. There wasn't a technical person in the panel.

Answer (score 5):

*Asking* to be involved would probably come across as presumptuous, *offering* to help out however probably wouldn't.

> I'd you'd like I'm happy to sit in on the interviews for my replacement? Since I know the role and what it entails I may be able to help determine if the candidate is suitable?

Comment: They wouldn't even probably wanted me to be involved in the decision process (that's the boundary I don't want to break). What if I'd add that I can  ask follow-up questions that are specific to projects I'm working on...

Comment: @user3877489 If you already recognize that they don't want you to be involved in the interview process, why wouldn't you want to just stay out of it? Why are you so desperate to get involved that you are thinking in terms of, "If I say this, will they change their mind"?

Comment: @MaskedMan I'm the one who will be training this person to takeover the projects, I believe it's a good start knowing their skills and capabilities.

Comment: @user3877489 Then you should include that detail in the question, otherwise it just sounds like you have already moved into the new role and want to be involved in the interview for no reason.